# Including for loop in subsets

Tags: algorithm, date, rstudio, subset, logistics

I want to calculate the weekly averages of the the load for two ships with containers. One ship sails at Sunday and the other on Wednesday. I have a big excel file with bookings.I will load up a small part of this file in the following link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxHTClTkrQzIzZzG5vXXnvKtV0_az83PGJ2ghBaAQr0/edit?usp=sharing

The first ship gets the containers that should be delivered on Monday (Mo), Tuesday(Di) and Wednesday (Mi). The second ship should deliver the containers demanded in the other port for Thursday (Do), Friday (Fr), Saturday(Sa) and Sunday(So). The data contains information about the containers from 2017-01-01 till 2018-07-31. These are 82 full weeks. I would like to make a vector with length 82, with each number the amount of containers of the days combined for that week. For example, the first number of the vector should be the demand of containers for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday in the first week. So, I want to create a vector, one per ship, that contains information about the amount of containers that should be loaded on this ship. A vector of 82 weeks, to see which weeks we had low demand and the mean etc.

Can anyone please help me?

```
Here is the beginning of my code:

 containers <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxHTClTkrQzIzZzG5vXXnvKtV0_az83PGJ2ghBaAQr0/edit?usp=sharing"

#Containers between Rotterdam and Duisburg
containersRTMDUI <- subset(containers, containers$Laadhaven == "Rotterdam" & containers$Loshaven == "Duisburg")

#I used to do this in subsets, because I could not make a loop
Week1 <- subset(containersRTMDUI, containersRTMDUI$Datum1 >= "2017-01-02" & 
containersRTMDUI$Datum1 < "2017-01-09" & containersRTMDUI$Dag1 = "Mo" & 
containersRTMDUI$Dag1 = "Di" &containersRTMDUI$Dag1 = "Mi")
Week2 <- subset(etc..)
```

Of course, the hard point comes by the fact that for some days there is no demand.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oke. Give me a moment please

Comment: Is this the `R` programming language? If so, I'd add a tag to that effect...

Comment: Done. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it.  One approach with data.table:

```
# read in data as a data.table
    library(data.table)
    dt <- data.table(read.csv("path/to/file", stringsAsFactors = F))

# rename variables to english (
# there are shorter ways to do this, but I like to keep track)
    setnames(dt, old = "ISO",          new = "containter_type")
    setnames(dt, old = "F.E",          new = "full_empty")
    setnames(dt, old = "Gewicht",      new = "weight")
    setnames(dt, old = "Laadhaven",    new = "pickup_port")
    setnames(dt, old = "Laadterminal", new = "pickup_terminal")
    setnames(dt, old = "Loshaven",     new = "dropoff_port")
    setnames(dt, old = "Losterminal",  new = "dropoff_terminal")
    setnames(dt, old = "Datum1",       new = "pickup_date")
    setnames(dt, old = "Dag1",         new = "pickup_dow")
    setnames(dt, old = "Datum2",       new = "dropoff_date")
    setnames(dt, old = "Dag2",         new = "dropoff_dow")

# convert date variable to date-type (instead of factor/string)
    dt[ , pickup_date  := as.Date(pickup_date,  "%d.%m.%Y")]
    dt[ , dropoff_date := as.Date(dropoff_date, "%d.%m.%Y")]

# create a week variable
    dt[ , week := lubridate::week(pickup_date)]

# create a variable (MTW) by day-of-week
# MTW=1 for mon, tues, wed; MTW=0 for thurs, fri, sat, sun
    dt[ , MTW := pickup_dow %in% c("Mo", "Di", "Mi")]

# count the number of rows by week and MTW
    result <- dt[ , .(nrows = .N), by=.(week, MTW)]

# print result
    result

# fill in 0 weeks
    dt2 <- data.table(week = rep(1:7, each=2), MTW = rep(c(T,F), each=7))
    result <- merge(result, dt2, by=c("week", "MTW"), all=T)
    result[is.na(nrows), nrows := 0]

# print updated result
    result
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, but that is not exactly what I was looking for. Every row in the dataset stands for one container trip. So, ISO is the container type, F/E means if the container is full or empty. Gewicht is the weight, Laadhaven means the port where it is pickup, with Datum1 the date that the container can be picked up. Loshaven is the port where it should be dropped. The ship makes two journeys, twice per week from Rotterdam to Duisburg and back. He is on Wednesdays and Sundays in Rotterdam.

Comment: So I would like to come up with two vectors, both with the length of 83, the amount of weeks in the period 2017-01-01 2018-07-31. One trip is filled with containers for Sunday, Monday and Tuesday, the other with the four other days. Is by myvalues, i would like to have the amount of rows of the dataframe and not the mean of the Gewicht.

Comment: Hey @BobD., I did an extensive edit of the code I provided.  Take a look and let me know if this new code does the job.  Note that I only used `Dat1` to determine the "Sun, Mon, Tues" part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. I will try this again.